# Primefaces hotkey while input has focus

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, hotkeys

I’m developing web app using Primefaces and one of the requirements is that hotkeys should work. And they do but there is a catch. While reading documentation I found out that hotkeys hotkey will not be triggered if there is a focused input on page. And this is big show stopper for us. Is there a way to make at least some hotkeys like <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd> etc. work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to manually bind the hotkeys to the inputs you choose.

I don't know your personal needs, but the following code (in jQuery) will bind it to *all input, textarea, select and button elements.*

```
$(':input').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 112) {  //you could also make a switch :)
        alert('f1 pressed!');  //do what you want
    }
    if (event.which == 113) {
        alert('f2 pressed!');  //do what you want
    }
    //...
})
```

Also don't delete your `p:hotkey`to continue with its normal behavior.

Note: Search for javascript keycode if you want to know more codes.